# Capturing Data for sync in offline Mode SharePoint Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-form, powerapp, offline-sync

What if we need to capture data in offline mode on smartphones and tablets? Later this data needs to be synchronized with the SharePoint Online lists and libraries. Usually, users will be an area where internet connectivity might not be available. Power-apps could be an option here but it is not suitable for very complex 
scenarios, where complex forms are to be built.

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is Power-apps support offline mode?**

- In short, **Yes**.

**In May 2017 new PowerApps release**, there are new improvements for Running apps while being offline, and Providing some support for offline data caching.

- Launching the PowerApps mobile player app offline
- Running apps while being offline
- Determine when your app is online or offline or in a metered connection by using the Connection signal object.
- Leverage existing formulas such as LoadData and SaveData for basic data storage while offline.

For more details, check [Build offline apps with new PowerApps capabilities](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-offline-apps-with-new-powerapps-capabilities/)

---

**Is it suitable for Complex forms?**

It depends on the type of your form complexity, However, in general, it's not suitable 100% for complex scenarios.

**Alternatives.**

- Read more about the [capability of Power Apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/) and match it with your complex scenarios.
- Check any other 3rd party tool that matches your requirements.
- Go back to InfoPath ([Not recommended because it will not be supported soon](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)).
- Build your custom Mobile App solutions and integrate it with the SharePoint APIs.